# Insert into query with 4 tables joint

Tags: mysql, join

I have 5 tables :

=>posts

ID

post_author

post_content

post_title

post_status

post_name

=>items

id

title

category

item

=>terms

term_id  //the category id

category  //items.category

slug

=>term_taxonomy

term_taxonomy_id

term_id     //the  category id

taxonomy         //the category name

=>term_relationships

object_id                // posts.ID

term_taxonomy_id

I think the query should be like this :

---

insert into term_relationships (object_id,term_taxonomy_id) 
select a.ID, b.term_taxonomy_id from posts a, term_taxonomy b,
where  terms.category = item.category

---

How can I do an insert query with 4 tables joint  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you need to something like this:

```
INSERT INTO term_relationships
([object_id], term_taxonomy)
(SELECT a.[ID], b.term_taxonomy_id
FROM items i
INNER JOIN posts a
ON i.title = p.post_title
INNER JOIN terms t
ON i.category = t.category
INNER JOIN term_taxonomy b
ON b.term_id = i.category
```

BUT - I do not know if you want INNER JOINs between your tables. You might want OUTER JOINs or a combination of INNER and OUTER JOINs. There's no way for me to know without knowing *how* you want the data to combine

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JOINs. It's not completely possible to answer your question without knowing *how* you want to JOIN the tables. I'd suggest looking at [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/07/22/the-simplification-of-join-simple-example-of-how-t-sql-join-work.aspx?Redirected=true)

Comment: the mysql query that i need should be something like this : insert into term_relationships (object_id,term_taxonomy_id) select a.ID, b.term_taxonomy_id from posts a, term_taxonomy b, where terms.category = item.category

Comment: You can't JOIN two tables based on the relationship of columns from two differen tables. If you want to JOIN posts and term_taxonomy, what is the column that they have in common? It looks to me like items.category = terms.category = term_taxonomy.term_id and posts.post_title = items.title. Is that true?

Comment: yes  items.category = terms.category = term_taxonomy.term_id and posts.post_title = items.title